# How to write Linux line breaks with PowerShell and System.IO.StreamWriter

Tags: powershell, newline

I need to write Linux-style line breaks from PowerShell using a `System.IO.StreamWriter` (for performance reasons):

```
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "path\to\file"
$writer.WriteLine("{0};{1}", $timestamp, $value)
```

I'm close to solution : `System.IO.StreamWriter` has a `NewLine` property but it does not work as expected:

```
$writer.NewLine = "\n"
$writer.WriteLine("{0};{1}", "23/12/2014", 45000)
$writer.WriteLine("{0};{1}", "24/12/2014", 54000)
```

produces:

```
23/12/2014;45000\n24/12/2014;54000\n...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell double quoted strings, use a back-tick as the escape character (not backslash).

Try

```
$writer.NewLine = "`n"
```